# biblatex doi setting refsection

Tags: biblatex, subdividing, doi

I am using `biblatex` with biber to create multiple bibliographies within one document. Generally, I want the doi to be printed. Hence, I set `doi=true`. But for one particular bibliography, created within `\refsection`, I want to suppress the doi. Is it possible to change the doi setting for one refsection only? I could use an alternative bibfile for this section and remove all doi-entries from this files. But just changing a setting would be more convenient. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The various `biblatex` 'print'/'don't print' options are set up as 'toggles' of the form `bbx:<name>`. As such, they can be altered using `\toggletrue`/`\togglefalse` from the `etoolbox` package. You should therefore be able to do

```
\togglefalse{bbx:doi}
```

just before your `\printbibliography` to turn off DOI printing. You'll need

```
\toggletrue{bbx:doi}
```

to turn it back on again.

Comment: Thanks, it perfectly does the job. But it seems that it is working only for the style-specific biblatex options (doi,isbn,url,eprint). Is it possible to apply the same methodology to other bibtex items (like volume, number,...), too?

Comment: @A.Groh It works for optional items set up suing the 'toggle' system: basically the core doi/url/... stuff and others where that model has been followed. The style files used by `biblatex` are customisable at the LaTeX level, but that's a bit more involved, or using the Biber back-end you can 'filter' the data returned to `biblatex`. However, I think both of those approach are not the best for something simple like DOI, so I'd say constitute a different question!